# How can I pass null arguments to my Java main method using run configuration arguments in Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, null, arguments

I'm trying to run a main method that requires four arguments, but the last one can be null (If #4 is null, use the string value in #2 as input.  If #4 is NOT null, use #4 as a file path and use the string in that file as input instead. Bad coding, I didn't write it).  However, I'm having trouble getting Eclipse to accept that fourth argument as null.

If I put anything on the fourth line, it takes it as a string.  If I put nothing, then it only processes three arguments.

Does anyone know how to get it to accept a null value through the run configuration arguments?

Thanks in advance,

Brandon

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The arguments can never be `null`. They just won't exist, so what you need to do is to check the length of your arguments.

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    // Check how many arguments were passed in
    if(args.length == 3)
    {     
        //the last arguement is null
    }
}
```

Comment: That'll work, I'll just have to tweak the code and school the guy that tried to use an "args[3] == null" conditional.  Thanks!